# Why trial division algorithm to find the prime factors of $N$ is $O(\sqrt{N})$, even though you need to check after $\sqrt{N}$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-factorization

I have understood that to check if $N$ is prime, it is enough to check up to $\sqrt{N}$ because if it has divisor up to that point then it's composite number. However, if you want to count all the prime factors of $N$, it is not enough to reach $\sqrt{N}$. For example, 14 has prime factors $2$ and $7$ but $\sqrt{14} < 4$. Am I missing something?

Comment: You test $14/2$ and see it gives the integer result $7$, so $2$ is a prime factor.  You then test $7/2$ and see it is not an integer so move to the next step.  You do not need to test $7/3$ since $3^2 >7$, so you know $7$ is prime and is the remaining prime factor.

Comment: It was that simple ?! Thank you for pointing out what i couldn't see. I will delete the question , though.

Comment: My http://www.se16.info/js/factor.htm uses exactly this method and for example will factor the 15-digit $123456789012345$ almost instantly.  Slightly slower with the prime $123456789012419$

Comment: Also , if we know all divisors $d$ upto $\sqrt{n}$ , we know all factors because the complement divisors are $\frac{n}{d}$

Comment: That trial division is fast for $15$-digit numbers is the result of the incredible increase of computational speed that has been achieved. This method is nevertheless not practiable for larger numbers. But this is another story.

Comment: @Henry, you may want to change the way to report the result. I inputed 2031 and it gave the result as 3.677 which can be confused for a number that is not an integer. 3,677 or 3-677 will be better although in French 3,677 is not an integer.

Comment: @user25406 That is a good point (for $123456789012345$ it gives `3.5.283.3851.7552031`) but since I wrote it 25 years ago when teaching myself JavaScript, I am unlikely to change it.  I am surprised it still works at all; my Java applets stopped working over a decade ago.